# Rails PG hstore value not getting saved

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to use PG hstore for the first time.

My form isn't saving the hstore data.
The console readout shows "data"=>{"charger"=>""}}. I'm thinking that it should be "data"=>{"charger"=>"6.6v"}}

Here is the HTML inspection:

[image]

Here is the console:

[image]

This is the form:

```
   <div class='clearfix attributeContainer'>
     <label class="label" for="vehicle_data">Data Attributes</label>
     <div class='row'>
       <p class='col-md-3 underline'>Name</p>
       <p class='col-md-3 underline'>Value</p>
     </div>

   <%= f.fields_for :data, @vehicle.data do |d| %>
      <% @vehicle.data.try(:each) do |key, value| %>
          <div class="row">
            <p class='col-md-3'>
              <%= text_field_tag key, key, :class => 'text_field dynamicAttributeName' %>
            </p>
            <p class='col-md-3'>
              <%= d.text_field key, :class => 'text_field', :value => value %>
            </p>
            <p class='col-md-1'>
              <a herf='#' class='btn removeRow'>X</a>
            </p>
          </div>
      <% end %>
  <%- end -%>

  <div class='row attributeTemplate <%= 'hide' if @vehicle.data.present? %>'>
    <p class='col-md-3'>
      <input class='text_field dynamicAttributeName' id='' name='' placeholder='New Attribute name' size='30' type='text' />
    </p>
    <p class='col-md-3'><input class='text_field' id='bar' name='' placeholder='value' size='30'  type='text'  /></p>
    <p class='col-md-1'><a herf='#' class='btn removeRow'>X</a></p>
  </div>
  <%= link_to 'Add Attribute', '#', :class => 'btn addAttribute btn-success' %>
</div>
```

This is the coffee script:

```
  $(".attributeContainer").delegate ".dynamicAttributeName", "keyup", (event) ->
    nameElem = $(this)
    valueElem = nameElem.closest(".row").children("p").children(".text_field")
    value = nameElem.val().toLowerCase()
    valueElem.attr "id", "vehicle_data_" + value
    valueElem.attr "name", "vehicle[data][" + value + "]"
    valueElem.attr "placeholder", "value for " + value
    return

  $(".attributeContainer").delegate ".removeRow", "click", ->
    console.log $(this).closest(".row")
    $(this).closest(".row").html ""
    return

  $(".addAttribute").on "click", ->
    contents = "<div class='row'>" + $(".attributeTemplate").html() + "</div>"
    $(this).before contents
    return
```

UPDATE1

I decided to try adding a record from the Rails Console and got an error:

```
2.0.0p353 :015 > c = Vehicle.create(name: “Test”, data: { battery: “LION”, charger: “6v” })
NameError: undefined local variable or method `“Test”' for main:Object
    from (irb):15
```

UDPATE2

I ended up making this change:

```
    valueElem = nameElem.closest(".row").children("p:nth-child(2)").children(".text_field")
```

Comment: So what's the problem? That your `date` is coming in wrong? Your controller is ignoring it? What does the model look like?

Comment: The console readout shows `"data"=>{"charger"=>""}}`.  I'm thinking that it should be `"data"=>{"charger"=>"6.6v"}}`.  The data field doesn't get saved.

Comment: You're duplicating `id` attributes in your HTML, that's invalid. You have multiple text fields with `name="vehicle[data][charger]` when presumably you want them to be in key/value pairs. `“` is not a double quote as far as Ruby is concerned, you want to use `"` or `'` in the console.

Comment: mu is too short - thanks to you, I got the console entry of a record working. Now I'm looking into the multiple text fields named the same.  I'm not sure what name the second one should have.  Thanks!

Comment: mu is too short, if you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks!